# Work with 2 dropdown items in jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 same dropdown lists in my web application that contains same values. Actually, these dropdown lists are for account numbers.
I want to avoid selecting two same items from these lists.
For example if user selects item #1 from the first dropdown list, item #1 must be hided from second one (If this item was not be the first one - Index #0). Also, if user changes his selected item to #2, #1 in the second dropdown must be visibled.

I have written something, but it does not work well:

```
$('#d1').change(function(e) {
    index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
    if (index != 0) $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none');
});
```

Look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QTDXt/).

I think I need just a way to make all items visible before hiding the selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.siblings()`

```
$('#d1').change(function(e) {
    index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
  $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none').siblings().css('display','block');
});

​
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/QTDXt/10/

Comment: your way is beautiful. But test this: select `2`, and then select `---`. Now look at the result

Comment: ah, i see i'll try and fix it

Comment: again you are missing 3 items in second dropdown if you select `---` in the first dropdown after two changes

Comment: That's it. Thank you Anton, Blazemonger, and A. V

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to hide specific options. (I can't do it in Chrome.) Try disabling the option instead:

```
$('#d1').change(function(e) {
    index = this.selectedIndex;
    $('#d2 option').prop('disabled', false); // enable all options
    if (index != 0) {
        $('#d2').get(0).selectedIndex = 0; // so you don't disable the option after it's selected
        $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/QTDXt/6/

Comment: @Blazemnonger, select `1`, and then select `2`. Now look at the second dropdown. You will see 2 disabled items

Comment: I don't. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#d1').change(function(e) {
index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
if (index != 0) {
  $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').css('display','none');}
  $('#d2 option:eq(' + index + ')').siblings().css('display','block');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTDXt/9/)